# Comma between two dependent clauses that follow independent clause in the complex sentence

Tags: subordinate-clauses

Should I put a comma before "or" in such a sentence:

> You will receive an email if your request is approved **or** if additional documents are needed

I can't find any rules on the Internet.

**Only found the following:**

> In a complex sentence, the independent and dependent clauses can be put together in a variety of ways. For example:
> **Two dependents followed by an independent clause**: In this format, put a comma after each dependent clause.
>
> - As soon as I opened the door, and after I had kicked off my shoes, I had a sense that someone was in my house.

[Source](https://prowritingaid.com/complex-sentence)

---

But in my sentence I have Independent clause followed by two dependent.

Comment: Welcome to ELL. A convention here is that basic questions about punctuation are considered inappropriate, so some may vote to close yours. But I find your question to be beyond basic. As for your question itself, I’d say that whether to use the comma here is entirely up to author.

Comment: Many commas in English are optional, and this is one of them. If you don't know and you have to guess, I tell my students to put commas before "or".